# Is there an API to reflect on Flink savepoints?

Tags: apache-flink

I have a Flink savepoint. I would like to produce a report on it using an API preferably in Java. Thinking of the savepoint like a database, I would like to list the tables, the table schemas, the size of each table in terms of rows and bytes and to produce statistics on the row sizes in bytes (min, max, average, std. dev., etc.). The API described [here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.14/docs/libs/state_processor_api/) assumes that the db schema is known (continuing the db analogy). Is there an API to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, Flink is no such API. normally savepoint should not be a reporter. I recommend using custom metrics do it. see: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/ops/metrics/.(I really want to add a comment, but I dont have enough reputation, I hope it won't bother you)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Metrics don't quite fit my use case of having an existing savepoint and wanting to explore it. I will accept your answer as being "no" to my question though.